# Visual Studio 2012 Removes inkPicture Control Every Time I Open My Project

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, microsoft.ink

The inKpicture control was not in the tool box by default.  I had to add it by right clicking inside the tool box, selecting "choose items", browsing to the microsoft.ink.dll, and finally selecting the inkPicture control.

Upon adding the inkPicture control to the toolbox, I am able to drag the control onto my form, style it, and test it by running the application from within Visual Studio.  I can proceed to build and publish the application without errors.  I can then run the application on my production machine as well as other PCs without issues.  The inkPicture control works fine, exactly as expected.

The problem is that every time I close my project solution in Visual Studio and then re-open it, the inkPicture is missing and I get the following errors:

[image: inkPicture Missing Error]

I have made sure that the Microsoft.ink.dll is referenced and it is included in my project's list of references as well as in the "using" statement.  I don't have any trouble building the project when the inkPicture is included.

Every time I re-open my project I have to remove all references to inkPicture1 from my form Designer.cs and then re-add the inkPicture control and re style it, which as can be imaged is a real pain.

Can someone please tell me why I keep having this problem?  What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Sounds like GAC trouble.  Document the Path property value you see in the Properties window when you select the reference.

Comment: This is what is in the path property for Microsoft.ink: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Tablet PC Platform SDK\Include\Microsoft.Ink.dll

Comment: Update:  I tried copying the Microsoft.ink.dll to my project folder.  I removed the reference, removed the control from the toolbox, re-added the reference from the new location, and finally re-added the inkPicture control to the toolbox using the new location, but I'm still having the same issue...

Comment: On my machine it is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Ink\Microsoft.Ink.dll.  After adding it to a project I get a path to the GAC.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! I checked that path on my machine and sure enough there was a version of Microsoft.Ink that was newer than the one I was trying to use.  When I use the newer DLL from the path mentioned above, I still do not get a path to the GAC displayed in the path property, but the inkPicture control no longer disappears when I close and re-open my project... Thanks again, you're a genius! +1

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else finding this in the future, I was able to resolve the issue by going into the Microsoft.Ink reference properties, and setting 'Specific Version' to False.  After that, I was able to go into design view without any issues.  I believe it was trying to use a version that was incorrect for the implementation we had.