# Converting Ink to Base64 and then to Image gets shapes cropped

Tags: vb.net, image, base64, microsoft.ink

I am using the function below to convert some ink shapes I have drawn on a picturebox control to Base64

```
  Function GetBase64(ByVal InkCollector As InkCollector) As String
    Dim utf8 As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
    InkCollector.Enabled = False
    Return utf8.GetString(InkCollector.Ink.Save(PersistenceFormat.Base64InkSerializedFormat, CompressionMode.Maximum))
    InkCollector.Enabled = True
  End Function
```

I can then use the string to reproduce the sketch into a new image by feeding it to this function:

```
  Function Base64toImage(ByVal Base64 As String) As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim utf8 As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim imgSig As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim tmploadedInk As Ink = New Ink()
    Dim strGIF As String
    Dim imageBytes() As Byte
    Dim MS As MemoryStream

    'Load the Base64 String in Format(PersistenceFormat = Base64InkSerializedFormat) as ink
    tmploadedInk.Load(utf8.GetBytes(Base64))
    'Convert the ink to Base64 String in format (PersistenceFormat.Gif, CompressionMode.Maximum)
    strGIF = Convert.ToBase64String(tmploadedInk.Save(PersistenceFormat.Gif, CompressionMode.Maximum))
    'Convert Base64 String to Byte Array
    imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(strGIF)

    MS = New MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length)

    ' Convert byte[] to Image
    MS.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length)

    imgSig = Image.FromStream(MS, True)

    Return imgSig
  End Function
```

This works fine except for the fact the shapes are cropped and therefore they get aligned to the top left corner of the generated image. If I use a line of code like below:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Signiture.Base64toImage(Signiture.GetBase64(Sketch_InkCollector))
```

The shapes appear at the top left and ignore the fact that they might have been drawn at the center of the original picture box. I believe that the positioning data is being properly saved into the Base64 string, but are somehow being ignored when the shapes are transferred to the image variable. The reason I believe this is because when I use the function below with the Base64 string, the shapes get placed properly in their original position.

```
  Sub SetBase64PictureBox(ByVal InkCollector As InkCollector, ByVal PictureBox As PictureBox, ByVal Base64 As String)
    Dim loadedInk As Ink = New Ink()
    Dim utf8 As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
    InkCollector.Enabled = False
    InkCollector.Ink.DeleteStrokes()        ' Clear all strokes
    loadedInk.Load(utf8.GetBytes(Base64))
    InkCollector.Ink = loadedInk
    InkCollector.Enabled = True
    PictureBox.Invalidate()
  End Sub
```

Thank you

Update:

Found a temporary solution in this link:

[InkPicture control - How to save both ink and image to an image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008399/inkpicture-control-how-to-save-both-ink-and-image-to-an-image-file?rq=1)

It is not exactly what I was after but the end result is the same since I wanted to the combined picture and the ink strokes into an image to show in a PDF file.